# cannot connect to parents slot

Tags: qt

I thought I was beginning to understand this but it seems not.

I am trying to connect together a stacked widget so that the children can send a message to the parent to tell it to change the view. The QStackedWidget is a child of the main window and its pages are promoted fomrs that I created myself. I think that's the right way to do it?

So within one of the children forms I tried the following:

```
// Set up a mapping between the buttons and the pages
QSignalMapper *mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

mapper->setMapping(ui->automatedButton, 1); // Value of the index
connect(ui->automatedButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()));

connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), ((QStackedWidget*)parentWidget()), SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I click the button and nothing changes. However if i do this:

```
void MySelectionForm::on_automatedButton_clicked()
{
    ((QStackedWidget*)parentWidget())->setCurrentIndex(1);
}
```

Which I thought was the same as what I was doing before?

I do see on message when running which I guess is associated:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect QSignalMapper::mapped(int) to (null)::setCurrentIndex(int)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked that `parentItem()` is not returning `NULL` when you call `QObject::connect()`? It sounds like maybe the parent item is being set *after* the constructor, which would mean that `parentItem()` would indeed return `NULL`. I suspect that might be how Qt Designer rolls. If so, you would need to connect the signal/slot outside of the constructor, either in another method (one that is not called inside the constructor), or outside of the child altogether.

Comment: Ahhh, that was very useful. I took the forms out of the designer and added them manually in the MainWindow constructor setting the parent to be the stacked container and it now works as expected. There might be another way to do it via the designer but this is okay for now until I work it out so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to the message,

```
((QStackedWidget*)parentWidget()), SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
```

leads to

```
(null)::setCurrentIndex(int)
```

which means `parentWidget()` is `NULL`.

This basically means that the forms are not a child of the `QStackedWidget`.
If you create your forms manually, you have to do something like this

```
MyForm *form = new MyForm( ui->stackedWidget );
```

Comment: I hadn't done them manually which I though meant they would be okay but possibly it is becuase of how I created them. More time in the framework and it would probably be easy. I created them manually as you mentioned and indeed that works.